# Are collection changes observed on a Realm `Results` object guaranteed to be in sync with all chained `Results` objects?

Tags: realm

Suppose I have two `Results`, the second chained from the first with a `filter`. In this case it's an `allPeople` collection and an `adults` collection that just filters for people 18 or older.

```
let realm = try! Realm()

let sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(keyPath: "lastName", ascending: true),
                       SortDescriptor(keyPath: "firstName", ascending: true)]

let allPeople = realm.objects(Person.self).sorted(by: sortDescriptors)

let adults = allPeople.filter("age >= 18")

allPeople.addNotificationBlock { changes in
    // Are the collections in sync here?
}
```

Are the changes in the notification block guaranteed to be reflected in both the `allPeople` collection and the `adults` collection? Is it possible for the two collections to be out of sync while I'm handling a change notification?

Comment: Change notifications are called only after the Realm instance, has updated its version and all Results have been notified of the Realm instance update, afaik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire Realm and all associated objects are advanced atomically, and it should not be possible to ever observe inconsistent state. Within the notification block all Realm objects and Results will reflect the new version that the notification is for.

The only caveat is that obviously multiple notification blocks cannot be called at the same time, so if you had notifications for both `allPeople` and `adults` you could not rely on the other notification having already done its thing.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected this must be the case, but it's good to get confirmation before I write a bunch of code relying on it.